# Can't use Route

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Route("/) does not work.

I already tried to reinstall annotations and Symfony with Composer.

My routes.yaml :

```yaml
index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\ArticleController::homepage
```

My ArticleController.php :

```php
namespace App\Controller;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;


class ArticleController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function homepage()
    {
        return new Response("TEST");
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/news/test-test")
     */
    public function show()
    {
        return new Response("FUTURE");
    }
}
```

The page always shows the public/index.php, but it should show "FUTURE" ;)

Comment: The page should show you "FUTURE" when you run localhost/.../news/test-test URL I think.

Comment: Which url are you going to ? And what do you expect to get from it ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your routes as given on https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/debug.html? Additionally, try clearing Symfony's cache

Answer (score 1):

in your config folder you should find a folder called routes inside it should be a file called annotations.yaml which contains the following :

```
controllers:
resource: ../../src/Controller/
type: annotation
```

if you have this you should get "TEST" when you go to ("/") 
and you get "FUTURE" when you go to (/news/test-test)

and make sure to clear the cache if it did not

and you have to comment every thing inside routes.yml

Answer (score 0):

Like Ali Mhanna said, check first `annotations.yaml`.

Then, according to Symfony documentation (read it, it can help ;), run `php bin/console debug:router`

If you see your route, your route is working.